# Kinetic Energy Evaluation Integral Evaluation Program

Tags: computational-chemistry

I'm reading Ostlund's *Modern Quantum Chemistry*. In Appendix A, the kinetic energy integral is evaluated using the Gaussian Basis functions to be

> $$
> \left(A\left| -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 \right| B\right) =
> \alpha\beta/(\alpha + \beta)[3 - 2\alpha\beta/(\alpha + \beta) |\mathbf{R}_A - \mathbf{R}_B|^2][\pi/(\alpha + \beta)]^{3/2} \\
> \times \exp [-\alpha\beta/(\alpha + \beta)|\mathbf{R}_A - \mathbf{R}_B|^2]
> \tag{A.11}\label{kin-en.int}
> $$

So, in the integral evaluation the Gaussian functions themselves are not used, but in the computer program  he is evaluating the integral using

```
T11=T11+T(A1(I),A1(J),0.0D0)*D1(I)*D1(J)
```

The function `T()` is calculating the equation above \eqref{kin-en.int}.

I can't understand why he is multiplying by `D1` and `D2` which are the Gaussian functions themselves.
$$g_\mathrm{1s}(\alpha) = (2\alpha/\pi)^{3/4}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha\mathbf{r}^2}$$

Comment: Just a comment, if you are looking to write your own integral code, I highly recommend taking a look at the following link https://joshuagoings.com/2017/04/28/integrals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for the Kinetic Energy matrix element that you quote is for two unnormalised 1s Gaussians. The d factors contain the normalisation factors and the contraction coefficients - look more carefully at the code, you have got it slightly wrong what the d's represent.

Talking of the code please, *Please* don't use that as a model for your own Fortran - that style is getting on for 50 years out of date!

Comment: Thank you Ian for your answer, I'm using another java version, I just wanted to quote the exact line from the book.

Comment: He is using T11,T22 and T12. I understand that T11 is the kinetic energy of the first atom, T22 is for kinetic energy of the second atom, what is T12 used for?. Thank you

Comment: Best to ask a separate question but (without looking at the book) think matrices is my guess